# Unity 5.3 - Input field wont detect first "return" key when pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to double press "return" key for the value to be submitted!
It was working fine like 2 hours ago(i only needed to press return once), but then i restarted Unity and now i need to double press "return" for the value to be submitted.

Update #2

I have a script attached to the canvas that is holding the Input Field.
The code as follows :-

```
public class Example: MonoBehaviour {
    public InputField inputField; 

    void Start () {
    }

    void Update () {
    HandleUserInput ();
    }

    void HandleUserInput() 
    {

    if (inputField.isFocused && inputField.text != "" && (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Return) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.KeypadEnter))) {
        Debug.Log ("Pressed");
        //Do stuff
        inputField.text = ""; //Clear Inputfield text
        inputField.ActivateInputField(); //Re-focus on the input field
        inputField.Select ();//Re-focus on the input field
    }
    }
```

When i play the scene, and type in the field and press the first return, the Log wont show anything, but when i press it again it shows "Pressed".

Update #3

I found some kind of solution, if i remove
    "inputField.isFocused"
The input field will detect the first "Return" key.
But still, in my case, if the input field had some text in it then the user clicked anywhere else in the scene then pressed enter, the input field will submit it.

Please advice

Comment: What Unity version and what is your input filed settings? It would be good if you post picture of the settings. I will advice you to delete the current one then create a new one and see if that will solve your problem.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Ok I see your problem. It requires the enter key to be pressed multiple times. You want it to be once?

Comment: Yea exactly, the solution i used is okay but not what i want tbh

Comment: Ok Check my anwser

Comment: thanks alot dude :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to do this manually. You need to use the Event System to register and receive events from `InputField`. Register to `InputField` submit event with `InputField.onEndEdit`, to get a callback when there is a submit on an `InputField`. You can also use `inputField.onValueChanged` to check when input changed. You can perform the `null` check in the callback functions:

```
public class Example: MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField inputField;
    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
    }

    //Called when Input changes
    private void inputSubmitCallBack()
    {
        Debug.Log("Input Submitted");
        inputField.text = ""; //Clear Inputfield text
        inputField.ActivateInputField(); //Re-focus on the input field
        inputField.Select();//Re-focus on the input field
    }

    //Called when Input is submitted
    private void inputChangedCallBack()
    {
        Debug.Log("Input Changed");
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        //Register InputField Events
        inputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(delegate { inputSubmitCallBack(); });
        inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { inputChangedCallBack(); });
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        //Un-Register InputField Events
        inputField.onEndEdit.RemoveAllListeners();
        inputField.onValueChanged.RemoveAllListeners();
    }
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity: I would have written `inputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(inputSubmitCallBack);` Why did you use the `delegate {}` construction?

Comment: @frankhermes That would have worked for `Button` (`Button.onClick.AddListener(inputSubmitCallBack);`). It wouldn't work for `InputField` events.`inputSubmitCallBack` will need to have the string parameter for it to work. You will get compile time error if you try it. With `delegate` you can call any function with parameter or no parameter instead of using the one with parameter Unity wants you to call. I also use `delegate` so that I can specify as many parameter as possible when working with many 'Buttons`. It allows me to use specials ids and only one callback function for all Buttons .

Comment: For anyone googling here, these days it's much easier to just `Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Return)` .  Then, do whatever you wish based on the state of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this problem is to check `inputField.isFocused` from the previous frame, because pressing the button makes `inputField.isFocused` turn to false.

Answer (score 1):

## It's this simple

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Return)) { YourSubmitFunction(); }
    }
```

Comment: It is not simple, see the answer of gopla29 below. When pressing the return key, the input field looses focus.

Comment: hi @Scriptman - hmm, when you tap Return, the input field ***is supposed to lose focus!!!***  Can you explain an example of what you mean?

Comment: I made a chat box, and I had the following code in my Update function: `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) && inputField.isFocused) { sendMsgToServer(); }`
But isFocused is false, so I set my own IsInputFocused variable.. (Note that i'm only using Unity for 3 days now).. Enter is also used ingame for other things, thats why I want to know if the enter is pressed in Chat :)

Comment: Right, on any system, iOS, Android, Unity, Web, if you have unusual needs for input fields, you will have to do some prorgramming.  Your first comment may confuse any beginners googling along here since, the code shown is the "normal" or "standard" way to do it in Unity on any normal, ordinary screen with input, like a form.  BTW you may find `onValidateInput` useful in your situation, good luck!