# Writing RTL in input field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write Persian in unity input fields. Persian is right to left language and it's alphabet is similar to Arabic.

I've found a [library](http://persiansilverlight.codeplex.com/) that converts and corrects the text. It's works just fine. When I'm showing the converted text into `Debug.Log()` everything is perfect but the problem is when I'm going to put corrected text into input field it would be reversed! I've tried to reversed the input field text but nothing happened!

Here's my code

```
 public InputField empName;

 PersianMaker pm;
 string tempStr = "";

 private void Start()
 {
     pm = new PersianMaker();
 }

 void OnGUI()
 {
     tempStr = "";

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(empName.text))
     {
         tempStr = pm.ToPersian(empName.text);
         tempStr = Regex.Replace(tempStr, @"\s+", " ");
         tempStr = tempStr.Trim();
         //empName.text = ReverseString(empName.text);
         //empName.text = tempStr;
         Debug.Log(tempStr);
     }
 }

 private string ReverseString(string s)
 {
     char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
     Array.Reverse(arr);
     return new string(arr);
 }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I did some research, but the only thing I found where people asking the same question and none of them had any answers either.

Comment: Mixing uGUI(`InputField`) with OnGUI? Don't do that. Remove the OnGUI code and use [`inputField.onEndEdit.AddListener`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38909364/3785314) to register to the submit event on the `InputField`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637032/arabic-input-fields-in-unity

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following open source library called [UPersian](https://github.com/ElectroGryphon/EGGA/tree/master/UPersian)

It works well and I think this is the only solution available out there.

[image]